# Cannot add a hangout meet in google calendar

Tags: google-calendar-api, hangouts-api, google-hangouts

I'd like to add a hangout meet in my google calendar when I insert the event

here is what I set

```
ConferenceData conferenceData = new ConferenceData();
CreateConferenceRequest createRequest = new CreateConferenceRequest();
createRequest.setRequestId("3qpalsoyh6");
conferenceData.setCreateRequest(createRequest);
conferenceData.setConferenceId("3qpalsoyh6");
event.setConferenceData(conferenceData);
```

I have right summary, time....

How to add a Hangouts meet in side!?

And is it possible to assign the host of the hangouts meet to one of the attendees instead of the account which cinsert the event !?

Can anyone help pls! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You are missing the parameter [`conferenceSolutionKey`](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/calendar/v3/java/latest/com/google/api/services/calendar/model/CreateConferenceRequest.html#setConferenceSolutionKey-com.google.api.services.calendar.model.ConferenceSolutionKey-)

It is necessary to specify the [`conferenceData.createRequest.conferenceSolutionKey.type`](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/calendar/v3/java/latest/com/google/api/services/calendar/model/ConferenceSolutionKey.html#setType-java.lang.String-) to add the Hangouts meeting.

The value for [type](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events) is `eventHangout` if you have a consumer account or `eventNamedHangout` if you are a GSuite User.

Comment: I'm trying in another case, that I use a gmail account to create a calendar with a eventHangout, it doesn't work. No hangouts in the calendar.

Comment: Did you specify the `conferenceDataVersion` to `1` as specified in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert)? https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/calendar/v3/java/latest/com/google/api/services/calendar/Calendar.Events.Insert.html#setConferenceDataVersion-java.lang.Integer-

Comment: can you tell me where i should add that, I can't found the function setConferenceDataVersion in java...

Comment: The java implementation can be found in the second link of my last comment. It's `Calendar.Events.Insert.setConferenceDataVersion`

Comment: Are there any different between eventNamedHangout  and hangoutMeet? i tried hangoutMeet but it soesn't work but eventNamedHangout   can.

Comment: The difference is your account. If you have a GSuite account - then you need to use `eventNamedHangout`. See [documentation about `conferenceData.createRequest.conferenceSolutionKey.type`](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events)

Comment: But i use eventNamedHangout it create a meet (https://meet.google.com/) actually it's what i need but the document said that i should use hangoutMeet

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211189/discussion-between-ziganotschka-and-).