# google calendar api says 400 bad request due to invalid value(conference properties)

Tags: java, api, rest, google-calendar-api

I am trying to insert `calendarList` using google calendar api v3.
The request body contains
`conferenceProperties` which allows `conferenceProperties.allowedConferenceSolutionTypes[]` as list `{eventHangout,eventNamedHangout,hangoutsMeet}`.

When I tried to insert using any of the  `conferenceProperties.allowedConferenceSolutionTypes[]`, the request throws "400 bad request".
But fortunately it works, when the request doesn't contain `conferenceProperties.allowedConferenceSolutionTypes[]`.

Why can't I select the "eventHangout" as `conferenceProperties.allowedConferenceSolutionTypes[]`?

```
Error: 400 bad request
"domain": "global",
"reason": "invalid",
"message": "Invalid Value"


HTTP: POST
https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList
request body: 
{
  "id": "XXX@group.calendar.google.com",
  "kind": "calendar#calendarListEntry",
  "summaryOverride": "",
  "colorId": "18",
  "backgroundColor": "#b99aff",
  "foregroundColor": "#000000",
  "selected": false,
  "hidden": false,
  "conferenceProperties": {
    "allowedConferenceSolutionTypes": [
      "eventHangout"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### `eventHangout` is only a valid value for a consumer account, while as a Gsuite user you need to chose a `eventNamedHangout`.

See the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events):

[image]
 and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61077574/cannot-add-a-hangout-meet-in-google-calendar/61080677#61080677).